# How do I client validate a razor view with input tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation

I am new to `MVC`. Is there any way to client validate a razor view having general inputs like

```
<input type-"text" id="txtFirstName" />
```

I have seen there are some ways to do it using DataAnnotation attribute in model and `@Html.Textbox` or `@Html.TextBoxFor`. But could not find something which can validate a pure HTML form element. I am using `Html.BeginForm` to render my form on page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want to do some validation on text box without using razor.you can come up with jquery validation.(rules and message.)

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$("#account_info").validate({
    rules: {
        phone_number: {
            required: true
        },
        recipient_name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6  // <-- removed underscore
        }
    },
    messages: {
        phone_number: {
            required: "this field is required"
        },
        recipient_name: {
            required: "Enter recipient name",
            minlength: "Name should be at least {0} characters long" // <-- removed underscore
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form');  // for demo
        return false;  // for demo
    }
});
```

});

Comment: I get typeError $(...).validate is not a function. This is how I added the code: var txtName = $("#txtName"); and then inside rules txtName:{required: true}. I also added Id and Name attributes of the form like this: using (Html.BeginForm(null, null FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmContactUs", name = "frmContractUs" })) which render correctly. Validate function start like $("#frmContactUs").validate({rules:{txtName:{required:true}}}); I tested jQuery is working as it is added in _Layout.chtml header. Am I missing something?

Comment: you need to load the main jquery script first.. and then the validate.js since validate requires jquery...(you are loading validate.hs first and jquery.js after that)  like................<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

Comment: Oh the path to jQuery validator was wrong! Now it works like a charm! Thanks so much

Comment: I still need 2 more reputations to be able to vote, currently I have 13. As soon as I gain those 2 points I will do it!